# SQL query for getting count of certain columns for every day across a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I have an 'actions' table in the following format:

| id | action | category_id | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fff | 3 | 12/11/2020 |
| 2 | aaa | 7 | 12/04/2021 |
| 3 | bbb | 3 | 04/01/2016 |

which is in a one-to-many relationship with 'categories' table (one category can have many actions, category_id is the foreign key above) in the following format:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat-1 |
| 2 | Cat-2 |

I need an API that receives a date range (start and end values) as an input an should return the total number of actions for all categories that take place for every day within that range, like so:

| day | Cat-1 | Cat-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2020 | 22 | 56 |
| 06/8/2011 | 56 | 78 |

Basically showing how many actions of a particular category took place per day in that date range.

My initial way of solving this was to fetch the data grouped by date and then manipulate that in the code. But I want to know if there's a way to do achieve this with SQL itself.

Comment: show us the query you've got so far

Comment: Get one row per day and category and then pivot to columns in your app code. Doing that in MySQL is a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   created_date                              as day
        ,count(case when name = 'Cat-1'then 1 end) as 'Cat-1'
        ,count(case when name = 'Cat-2'then 1 end) as 'Cat-2'
from     t join t2 using(id)
group by created_date
```

| day | Cat-1 | Cat-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-11 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-12-04 | 0 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5vM1IZRq)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For some reason, it works when I don't use a JOIN and execute the cases by id (CASE WHEN id = '1' ...). That returns the correct data in the correct format. But in order to use the NAME field and thereby using a JOIN, 0 rows are returned.